# Installing Windows XP Pro on a Raid 1 array without the driver floppy

Tags: windows-xp, installation, operating-systems, raid

I'm looking to install a Raid 1 array on my WinXP Pro file server/dvr to improve data redundancy at home. Since I would really hate to look for a floppy drive and cram it into my small computer case, I was wondering if there was any way I could somehow make XP install recognize my array?

I've heard about slipstreaming drivers and such, so I'm also wondering if something like that would work.

My install disc is a vanilla XP Pro install, without any service packs out of the box.

Comment: Would providing thedriver disk at install be that much more work than trying to add the driver to the XP media?

Comment: Yes because XP is hell bent on it being the floppy disk and my slim computer case doesn't have anywhere for me to place the drive. I'd have to leave the case open with the floppy drive hanging out, and then there's the issue of finding a floppy disk that works.

Comment: Hey thanks for fixing the raid level. Got confused there for a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use driver packs to slipstream "Mass storage" drivers into the XP CD. No more hunting for the latest driver, it has all of them.

Driver packs tutorial, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

Download software "Driverpacks Base"

http://driverpacks.net/downloads

You can install other driver packs besides the "Mass Storage", but this will bloat the size of the XP install to DVD size, The only driver packs I suggest to slipstream are

Mass Storage, Chipset, Lan, CPU

This will keep it a size to fit on a CD. If you want all the drivers slipstreamed it will require a DVD burner to make the DVD and a DVD drive on the target installation PC.

I don't change any of the default settings when using the software, just pick the driver packs you want to slipstream and create the ISO image.

If you use other customizing software for other reasons than drivers such as Nlite, use Nlite first then driver packs last or install problems will result. Only use DP to slip drivers, do not use Nlite for this task.

Start with clean unmodified Installation files when using DP for best results

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a look. If it proves to be simpler than nLite I'll mark you as answer.

Comment: It is simpler in the respect you don't have to search for the right driver, DP slips all the available mass storage drivers, windows finds and installs the proper one during setup, no mess no fuss. Be sure to read the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you'll want to slipstream this. For XP, you can [use nLite for this](http://www.nliteos.com/). You'll be guided through patching drivers in to the installer. For other people reading this in to the future, Vista users and the like can use [vLite](http://www.vlite.net/) to the same end, apparently.

You'll also be able to add other things like programs to be pre-installed and system updates, if you like.

Comment: Thanks! I've used nLite before so it should be a breeze provided I find the right drivers for the motherboard raid controller.